ExtAudioFileRead throwing AVAudioSessionErrorCodeResourceNotAvailable error on iOS and iPadOS 18
Calls to ExtAudioFileRead are throwing OSStatus 561145203 (AVAudioSessionErrorCodeResourceNotAvailable) on iOS and iPadOS 18 -- earlier versions of iOS have not exhibited this behavior. This is a longstanding code path that has suddenly seen a spike of these error codes since iOS 18's release.
e.g.
AudioBufferList audioFileBufferList;
audioFileBufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
audioFileBufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = clientAudioStreamBasicDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioFileBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = bytesToRead;
audioFileBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = (void*)mData;
                
UInt32 ui32FramesToRead = framesToRead;
OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileRead(file.audioFile, &ui32FramesToRead, &audioFileBufferList);
// 561145203 status

The following is also printed in the Xcode 16 console:
rt_sender::signal_wait_with_timeout failed: 22
AudioConverter -> 0x30268eae0: FillComplexBuffer out-of-process render returned 561145203

Has anyone else experienced troubles with iOS 18 in this area?

What codec are you using? AAC? A long time ago on iOS you had to think about hardware vs software codecs, and recreate the hardware ones after audio interruptions. Maybe this is something like that. You could try using the software codec to see if that helps - see the comments on the ExtAudioFile property kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer.

@GordonChilds thanks for your response. Yes, AAC. On your suggestion I attempted specifying kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer with ExtAudioFileSetProperty(file.audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, size, &codecManufacturer); but the error is still thrown. Is there something else about the audio file format that could be at play?

I don't know. Do you have some code I could run that reproduces the problem?

@GordonChilds I unfortunately don't have a focused example. I was able to prevent the error with some improved thread-handling. It looks like iOS 18 complained more about the inefficiencies there.

All's well that ends well.
